# Conky is too high in the top right

Tags: conky

- Xubuntu 12.10
- DE: XFCE

So I started this conky script

http://conky.sourceforge.net/conkyrc-brenden

(it is the very first .conkyrc file i nthe top left on http://conky.sourceforge.net/screenshots.html) and I only changed the font to Poly and the alignment to top_right. That's all. But now it literally is *too high* in the top, I can't see the first line (whatever it says--I don't know).

Although I am aware of http://conky.sourceforge.net/variables.html and http://conky.sourceforge.net/config_settings.html I am pretty clueless. What do I do? :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the answer myself. The solution was to increase the variable gap_y to a value higher than 29.

Answer (score 1):

This problem caused me no little trouble, for solve it i wrote a script in python3.
If you want to use it is [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/0aio94x9z32i9ws/conky.py)

The script launch conky with the configuration file "~/.conky/conkyrc" and risize it with "wmctrl".

Using:

```
conky.py 245 600
```

the conky window will be scaled to 245x600 px

Finally put the script in the startup list, and enjoy conky :)

If you know python modify the script as you wish.

Comment: I'm sorry, I truly do not understand your answer and what I should/could do with it. That's why I am kind of wary about downloading your python script, although I appreciate the effort.

Comment: Oh, sorry, I misunderstood, then re-reading I understand your problem. I realized that the Conky window was too high ...